# external jar for webcam class in java

Tags: java

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;


public class A {

    void main(String arg[]) {
        Webcam webcam = Webcam.getDefault();
        webcam.open();
        BufferedImage image = webcam.getImage();
        ImageIO.write(image, "JPG", new File("test.jpg"));
    }

}
```

I am using this code for taking photo through webcam, but Webcam class is not recognized by the eclipse, please tell which external jar I need to add for Webcam class.

Comment: You should know it...!!!

Comment: How are we supposed to know what you want to use?

Answer (score 0):

Check this website: I think Webcam Capture API is your need. maven-central contains your needed jars.

http://webcam-capture.sarxos.pl/